# Spring AOP and RequestMapping Annotations

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-aop

I am creating a class to audit calls to my Spring Boot app's controller classes:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ServiceAudit { //RequestMappingInterceptor {
@Pointcut("@annotation(requestMapping) && execution(* *(..))")
public void controller(RequestMapping requestMapping) {}

@Before("controller(requestMapping)")
public void advice(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint, RequestMapping requestMapping) {
    String url = requestMapping.value()[0];
    String httpMethod = requestMapping.method()[0].toString();
...
...
```

One of my Controller classes looks like this - with annotations at the class AND method level (which I can't change at this point):

```
RestController
@CrossOrigin
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@RequestMapping(value = "/applications")
public class ApplicationController {

     ...
     ...


@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Application> findById(@PathVariable Integer id) throws Exception {

  ...
  ...
}
```

I can pull the url, methodtype, parameters fine. However, what I am having a very hard time of doing is pulling the Controller class' annotation ('/applications') so I can build the full URL for my auditing table.

I know there are other options for auditing (like Spring Boot Actuator) but I need to use this approach with aspects for various reasons and am just stuck here. Spring's AnnotationUtils seems like it would be helpful but am stuck on the code to get class level annotations. Anyone ever done this?

UPDATE: 
Thanks. That didn't work. You're right - that was a superfluous piece and it worked when I removed the 'execution' part but still same issue.    Essentially, the issue is how to I get a class-level annotation in this case.  So, for my ApplicationsController class, how do I retrieve the '/applications' path defined at the class-level. I think it's in there, but it's nested so deep in the requestMapping object, I can't figure out how to extract it. For now, only solution I have is to create a HashMap for my controllers (ApplicationsController -> '/applications') and then use methodInvocation.targetClass as a key to that map. Not very elegant and requires maintenance when I add a controller.

Comment: try, removing execution(* *(..)) from point cut

Comment: Thanks. That didn't work. You're right - that was a superfluous piece and it worked when I removed that part but still same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can capture class level annotations like this:

```
@Pointcut("@target(classRequestMapping) && @annotation(requestMapping) && execution(* *(..))")
public void controller(RequestMapping classRequestMapping, RequestMapping requestMapping) {}

@Before("controller(classRequestMapping, requestMapping)")
public void advice(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint, RequestMapping classRequestMapping, RequestMapping requestMapping) {
    // do whatever you want with the value
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That was helpful.